# IOS - Imageview frame size weird settings

Tags: ios, imageview, scrollview

I have a photo with size is 320 x 2560, i use a scrollview and imageview to display on iPhone. but i dont know why, if i set the imageview.frame height to 2560, the image is not fully displayed, if i increase the height to 3660, full image is displayed. i am using xcode5 with storyboard

here is the code:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];
[self.imageView setImage:img];
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 3660);
//self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y,img.size.width, img.size.height);
[self.scollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((self.imageView.frame.size.width), (self.imageView.frame.size.height))];
```

Comment: try to reduce the height of the self.scrollView on 100.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? That can cause a host of issues like this. I would assume your logic would work with auto layout turned off. Don't think it will with it turned on.

Comment: disabled auto layout still not work. i use a webview to load the image now, because the image is download from internet. thx guys !